# Create a drop down from header without resizing header with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a header where there will be an image for each user. When I press the image there should be a dropdown menu with options such as log out and settings (similar to the user dropdown on facebook and similar pages). I have used a toggle effect with React

```
class Header extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showOptions: false
    };
}
 render() {
let dropDownMenu;
if(this.state.showOptions){
    dropDownMenu = <div className="dropDownMenu">Hello</div>
};
return (
 <header className="fullWidth">

 <div className="search">
    <p className="courses">Courses</p>

        <p>Search</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
        <img src="https://en.opensuse.org/images/0/0b/Icon-user.png" className="userImage" onClick={this._handleClickA.bind(this)}/>
        {dropDownMenu}
   </div>

  </header>
);
 }
 _handleClickA(){
this.setState({
    showOptions: !this.state.showOptions
});
 }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Header />, document.getElementById('header'));
```

I have considered to make the dropdown in another component and pass it to the header component but I couldn't get it to work so I was trying to do it this way. When I toggle it the whole header changes size and I only want it to create a dropdown with potential other color from the header.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `position:absolute` for your dropdown.

Also try to take a look to this component which is awesome [React-Tether](https://github.com/souporserious/react-tether)